# ng-include and $templateCache

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently am working on a big html file(7k+ lines of code). I have to refactor the whole thing. Person previously responsible for the code was using a method presented below to load specific templates into cache to be used via ng-include.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/templates/example.html">
    <p>Example</p>
</script>
```

Those templates also exist as separate html files.

My first idea was to use

```
$templateCache.put(url,content)
```

method during module.run() stage. It would be a perfect solution, if I could somehow pass template-url-path  as a second parameter(content) instead of passing actual html code.

Or perhaps should I just add templates via directive.templateUrl ?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it is important for you to have those templates cached once the app initially loads then I would just place those templates into their own files and put that templateUrl on those directives or routes.

**Edit:**

---

Angular will do a call for the template once during the lifespan of the application when that particular route or directive loads, and after that Angular will only go to the `$templateCache` service. So if you just specify a `templateUrl` on your directive, once that directive loads for the first time Angular will do an ajax call for that template and then store it in `$templateCache` for you. So having 100 directives on the page that use the `templateUrl` of `views/user.html` will do a call for that template once and then never again until the page completely reloads.

---

If using [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) or gulp-angular-templatecache like [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4201955/dan-moldovan) said is an option then I would go with that, especially for production builds.

Keep in mind though when using grunt-angular-templates, if you have a directive that references a templateUrl like `/views/main.html` and your have `views/main.html` loaded into your `$templateCache`, angular won't know to use it by default because it's missing the leading slash.

Comment: Is there any way I could load existing html templates into cash just by passing url patch as an attribute instead of passing an actual html-content like via $templateCache? The problem is that somewhere in the application there already all calls vis ng-include. Will the source to the directive be added to cash too(if I use templateUrl apporach)?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be what you are looking for but if you use a build system like `Gulp` or `Grunt` you may use something like [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) which basically packages all your templates, put them into `$templateCache` and makes a `templates` module out of them which you simply have to add as a dependency to your app.

Answer (score 1):

I compile all my templates to one templates.js file with with grunt [html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-common-html2js) task.

Recommend to have a look